# Map returning reference in java

Tags: java, dictionary, xstream

we have a map

```
 final Map<String, Date> releaseDate = new HashMap<String, Date>();
  ....#code to populate Map
  I have an object Movie movie =new Movie()
```

when I set the value movie.setReleaseDate(releaseDate.get("test");

I add this in xml file it's showing as

`<releaseDate reference="../../../movie/releaseDate"/>`

it's showing the reference not the value.

when I try like

```
 Date date = (Date)releaseDate.get("test").clone();
  movie.setReleaseDate(date);
```

then in xml file showing the correct value
`<releaseDate>2011-07-31 23:00:00.0 UTC </releaseDate>`

why map is returning the reference.How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You are not telling us everything? What is the connection between your movie class and the xml file?

Comment: And would you care to precise how and by which tool/library the XML is generated ? There is absolutely no way anyone can understand this question without context.

Comment: Without knowing more I'd have to guess but it might be because of object equality, i.e. if two movies share the exact same date instance the library you're using seems to put a reference (and I'm sure there's a good reason for this). Creating a new instance using `clone()` breaks that link.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention we used xstream TypeAliasMapping to generate XML from pojo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES)`.

See this page: http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html

*FYI: Simple Google search for [`xstream reference attribute`](https://www.google.com/search?q=xstream%20reference%20attribute&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) found me that link.*